# la app se detiene en algunos dispositivos

Tags: java, android, app

> hola a todos, he desarrolado mi app y funciona perfectamente en mi telefono, de hecho ya esta publicada en play store, pero a unos amigos les abre la app pero cuando dan clic en cualquier boton se cierra con el mensaje " la app se ha detenido" esto sucede en algunos dispositivos no en todos. el sdk esta definido bien, la aplicacion como dije antes, compila bien, en mi telefono con android 9 ejecuta bien, pero probé en uno con android 5.1.1 y no ejecuta. 
>   les dejo el xml y el gradle.

xml

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cabecera"
                android:layout_width="410dp"
                android:layout_height="93dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/cabecera2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uno"
                android:layout_width="207dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

                android:onClick="primeros_pasos"
                android:text="primeros pasos"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cabecera" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dos"
                android:layout_width="207dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="partisanos"
                android:text="Partisanos"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uno" />
```

el gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'



    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.codesgood:justifiedtextview:1.1.0' //Justificar texto
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Habría que ver que minSdkVersion tienes en el gradel, ya que parece que por ahí podrían ir los tiros.

Comment: minSdkVersion 14

Comment: Agrega los mètodos que se llaman al dar clic! ahí se puede encontrar el Problema y trata de agregar el error mostrado en el LogCat, por cierto tomate un tiempo para leer [ask] y realizar el [tour], saludos.

Comment: eleanys gracias, pero puedes ser mas especifica, soy novato en esto

Comment: tengo los metodos implementados, los botones funcionan bien, el problema es que en algunos dispositivos al dar clic en un boton se detiene la app

Comment: ya lo solucioné, el problema era que el activity que se debía abrir llevaba un texto en imagen, puse el texto directamente en un string y corre normal en los otros dispositivos. gracias a todos.

Comment: Porque en unos dispositivos no funcionaba, tienes varios archivos strings.xml? @AsherCacua

Comment: no se parece que cuando le ponia muchas imagenes a un layout se sobrecarga o no se que pasa pero se detiene si coloco muchas imagenes